# Modify a string in a file

Tags: perl

The following code tries to change nhours for 24, but it fails, and the original file after the execution becomes empty...and the out file doesn't get 24, still mantains nhours

```
rename($file, $file . '.bak');

open(IN, '<' . $file . '.bak') or die $!;

open(OUT, '>' . $file) or die $!;

while ( <IN> ) {

    s/nhours/24/g;
    print OUT $_;

    @args = ("$rundir/upp/run_unipost.bak");
    escriu(@args);
    system(@args) == 0 or die "system @args failed: $?";
}

close(IN);
close(OUT);

sub escriu {
    my @missatge = @_;
    chomp (my $hora = `date |awk '{print \$4}'`);
    print "----->  $hora @missatge\n";
}
```

and `run_unipost.bak` executes a process.

Comment: Why are there no error checks in your code? `rename`, `open`, `print`, `close` can all fail.

Comment: Don't use 2-arg open and bareword filehandles. Use 3-arg open and lexical variables instead (very modern feature, available since 2000).

Comment: This question contains an unclear problem description, a random code fragment (with no error checks and incomplete), and seemingly no attempts to debug the problem yourself. What do you expect from us without a [mcve]?

Comment: Don't use global file handle, use a local var `open my $fh, '<', 'file' or die`

Comment: Why would you shell out to `date` and `awk` just to get the time? That's just `use POSIX qw(strftime); my $time = strftime "%H:%M:%S", localtime;`.

Comment: I don't see any way that your output file can be empty. Is `$file` the same as `$rundir/upp/run_unipost.bak`? You should remove everything except the substitution and the `print` from your code and try again.

Comment: @melpomene: `POSIX`  is enormous. `use Time::Piece 'localtime'` and `my $time = localtime->hms`

Comment: Your file becomes empty because `open(OUT, '>' . $file)` destroys its contents before you read them.

Comment: Next time, please ask 1 question, and put that question in the title. That way, your question will be of much more help to other StackOverflow users.

Answer (score 1):

The code that I've been able to test works exactly as expected. So it looks like the problem is in the bits that I haven't been able to test.

- I don't know what `escriu()` does.
- I don't know what `run_unipost.bak` does.

Comment: I have completed my answer

Comment: @EnricAgudPique: Confused. I don't see an answer from you,